# Android App Bundle new language

Tags: android, android-studio, android-app-bundle

I've updated my application to the new Android App Bundle. I've uploaded a new App Bundle in the internal test track.

And now when I add a new language to my phone, it doesn't download the associated language for my app like we could expect it.

Is it specified when the new language will be downloaded?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What language is it? Is your app translated in that language? Also, what OS version is the device on? The language should be downloaded almost immediately if the device is on a connected network.

Comment: Tried with both spanish and italian. Yes the app is translated in that language. I tried with my galaxy S8 on Oreo but other people have the issue too. My app if you wanna try: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ifpen.gecoair&hl=en

Comment: Ok got it this time after 10m.

Answer (score 3):

When downloading the App if the language is not available in the Phone, Google Play was removing that language from the App because the language isn't installed on the phone.

In case you only want to show specific languages for your app, You can set it in argument as shown below in `build.gradle` file.

```
defaultConfig { 
     resConfigs "en", "ar", "fr"          
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to add play core dependency in your app. And follow the sample code

1. request language module

   ```
   val manager = SplitInstallManagerFactory.create(this)
   // Skip loading if the module already is installed. Perform success action     directly.
   if (manager.installedModules.contains(targetLocalName)) {
       onSuccessfulLoad(targetLocalName)
       return
   }

   val request = SplitInstallRequest.newBuilder()
       .addModule(targetLocalName)
       .build()

   // Load and install the requested feature module.
   manager.startInstall(request)
   ```
2. install split in your application and activity

   ```
   override fun attachBaseContext(newBase: Context) {
      val ctx = LanguageHelper.getLanguageConfigurationContext(newBase)
      super.attachBaseContext(ctx)
      SplitCompat.installActivity(this)
   }
   ```

You should reference doc and dynamic bundle demo 
[doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/dynamic-delivery#lang_resources)